# Globalization in jquery and asp.net. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, localization, globalization

Is there a jquery plugin for the globalization of asp.net web application? 
I have found only "Jquery Globalization from Microsoft" [Jquery Globalization](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx), but it seems like an died project. Right?

So, the only solution is using the "Asp.net Ajax Control Toolkit"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has "evolved" so to speak and has a new name now - Globalize. It should work with any JS library or environment and isn't dependent on jquery anymore.

News link: http://damianedwards.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/the-jquery-globalization-plugin-becomes-globalize/

GitHub: https://github.com/jquery/globalize

Don't have experiences with this library myself, but I guess you can figure it out by yourself easily :)